# How do I require two modules containing the same package?

Tags: java, java-module

My project has dependency [`dsl-json-java8`](https://github.com/ngs-doo/dsl-json/blob/master/java8/pom.xml#L7), which happens to have dependency [`dsl-json`](https://github.com/ngs-doo/dsl-json/blob/master/library/pom.xml#L7). These [do not yet boast Java 9's module gimmick as a feature](https://github.com/ngs-doo/dsl-json/issues/179).

For some reason, both dependencies contain package `com.dslplatform.json`, though they host [different](https://github.com/ngs-doo/dsl-json/tree/57fbff1477f21635f036af6c8864430e91d24050/java8/src/main/java/com/dslplatform/json) [classes](https://github.com/ngs-doo/dsl-json/tree/57fbff1477f21635f036af6c8864430e91d24050/library/src/main/java/com/dslplatform/json).

So, when I try adding both libraries to `module-info.java` as automatic modules,

```
module example {
    requires dsl.json;
    requires dsl.json.java8;
    ...
}
```

I get error "The package com.dslplatform.json is accessible from more than one module: dsl.json, dsl.json.java8" on lines like

```
import com.dslplatform.json.DslJson;
```

Even though no classes are in conflict, and these packages are not different versions of the same code.

So I get that this weird packaging is against the [principles of modules](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/modules.html#automatic-modules):

> The rule about not allowing split packages also counts for automatic modules. If multiple JAR files contain (and thus exports) the same Java package, then only one of these JAR files can be used as an automatic module.

But, you know. I don't have any use for this arbitrary restriction. I need this to work.

What's the right thing to do when your unmoduled dependencies export identically-named packages?

Comment: Why not just submit a PR to the project? Seems they're more than willing to do it, they just don't know how

Comment: In the meantime, you could [shade](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) their classes into your own JAR, give it any module-info you want, and push it to your company artifact repo (or [jitpack](https://jitpack.io/) if its not a work project). Then depend on that instead.

Comment: @Michael Both are reasonable proposals. Thinking...

Comment: Side note: The reason for two artifacts using the same package is often that one of the artifacts is using package-private classes or fields from the other artifact.  
Another alternative solution would be to simply not use the module system and to staty on the class path.  
(see also https://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/jigsaw-dev/2017-May/012808.html)